# Problem after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a PC with Ubuntu as the only OS in it.
I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2, but I reinstalled to update it.

Now I keep getting,

> This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode
>   butitlooks like there may be cxisting operating systems atready
>   installed using "BiOS compatibility mode"If you continue to install
>   Deblan In UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine Into
>   any BIOS mode operating systems later. if you wish to install in
>   UEFImode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the
>   existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish
>   to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should
>   choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.

Please help

Comment: It tells you that you have an other OS already installed in BIOS mode and that you are trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Normally you will want all OS's on a system to be installed in same mode.

Comment: @SorenA: Could you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

So, the way to check it - enable only UEFI mode in BIOS settings - <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> at boot screen (or its possible to choose type of boot at boot time on some hardware, by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or like so - look at boot screen for options and choose UEFI boot) and try to boot another OS. If it boots fine or no other OS needed - then choose UEFI install, otherwise choose BIOS compatibility.

If other OS fails to boot, enter BIOS settings and revert all booting options back as before. And install Ubuntu in BIOS compatibility boot.

@Soren It says "*may be* existing OS installed in...".

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that you might have an other OS already installed in BIOS mode and that you are trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Normally you will want all OS's on a system to be installed in same mode.